# Is my linux mint box vulnerable to Shell-Shock attacks? How might I remedy that?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, security, shellshock

Is it safe to use Linux Mint now, with ShellShock existing? If not, what can I do to use Mint safely?

Comment: Is your question about Mint specifically, or about all Linux systems, or about any Unix-like system that has bash installed?

Comment: The exploit is one that could be used to access the system *if* you have public services that invoke the shell, particularly if how those work isn't clear to you.  So, **if you aren't running a public server, don't worry** -- anyone who manages to access your system won't have to bother with shellshock because they've already accessed the system some other way.

Comment: @goldilocks so, this worry really isn't relevant to me if my Mint is going to be sued for desktop PC use. Great to know, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you patch your bash shell you should be okay :)

For more information on securing and patching the BASH shell check out this website:
https://shellshocker.net/

You can first try upgrading bash

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade bash
```

If no upgrades are available I suggest compiling it yourself, we will start off by making our directory to work in.

```
mkdir gnubash
cd gnubash
```

Now we will download the latest bash, along with the patches

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3.tar.gz
for i in $(seq -f "03g" 0 29); do wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/bash43-$i; done
tar zxvf bash-4.3.tar.gz 
cd bash-4.3
for i in $(seq -f "03g" 0 29); do patch -p0 < ../bash43-$i; done
```

Run this as root to configure and make the patches

```
sudo su -
./configure && make && make install
```

To see the results we can test a vulnerability:

```
env 'VAR=() { :;}; echo Bash is vulnerable!' 'FUNCTION()=() { :;}; echo Bash is vulnerable!' bash -c "echo Bash Test"
```

If the only thing that returns is "Bash Test" you have been patched :)

Comment: One problem with this: **You left the old bash on the system**, even if it the one in `/usr/local` now takes precedence.  You probably want to remove that, which is going to be tricky since it's part of the distro.  You could just replace the binary with the new one, e.g. `cp /usr/local/bin/bash /bin/` (presuming that's where the old one is) and *probably* that won't hurt anything.

Comment: @Christopher will all the terminal input be the same for Elementary OS?

Comment: @Michael Since Elementary OS is Debian based, the terminal input `should` be the same. That being said, I have not tested this method on it.